# How to convert a text variable to a python dataframe column and split rows by "\n"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

```
 fruit='Food\nName/Category\nApple\nFruit\nBanana\nFruit\nBread\nGrain\nTomato\nVegetable'
```

Hi folks, I have a text variable as above and I want to convert it to pandas dataframe column and split by "\n". I can transfer it to the df but don't know how to split rows based on "\n".

Expected results:
[image]

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: `pd.Series(fruit.split('\n'))`?

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame({'Col':fruit.split('\n')})`

Comment: also `fruit.splitlines()`

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @piRSquared even better indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `split` method to split the `fruit` string based on the `'\n'` string pattern:

```
fruit_list=fruit.split('\n')
```

You can then load `fruit_list` into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(fruit_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

fruit='Food\nName/Category\nApple\nFruit\nBanana\nFruit\nBread\nGrain\nTomato\nVegetable'

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit':fruit.split("\n")})
```

Output:

```
           fruit
0           Food
1  Name/Category
2          Apple
3          Fruit
4         Banana
5          Fruit
6          Bread
7          Grain
8         Tomato
9      Vegetable
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use split.

```
pd.DataFrame(fruit.split())
```